# Is it possible to disable Google Universal Search (not see videos & images in results)?

Tags: google-search

In 2007 Google introduced **Universal Search** (sometimes called blended search), and started **including images and videos** in the regular search results page.

**I don't want to see those results**. I know how to click the videos or images link at the top of the page and if I enter text in the search box it is because I am looking only for text.

It used to be possible to do a search at **Google.com/custom** to get the old-style simple search results page, but that link now results in an error:

```
your computer or network may be sending automated queries
```

No results are given.

**Is there any way to go back to the simple text-only Google results page?**

It would be preferable to do it by manipulating the query string so that I can replace my default search engine with simplified results.

Comment: What about **News**, **Shopping**, etc?

Comment: I'd prefer to exclude them but it's not as important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an elegant solution to this problem using **Google Custom Search**.

To see the result in action, go to this [custom search engine](http://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=000628392187335527771:2-d3w-aefr4).

To set up your own version, go to [google.com/cse](http://google.com/cse) and:

1. click "**create a custom search engine**"
2. put whatever you want on the setup page, but **use a nonexistent url** for the "sites to search" box
3. **click "next" twice** (change the look if you like)
4. click on the link "**change the basics**" under "**next steps**"
5. at the bottom of the "basics" page, check "**search the entire web but emphasize included sites**"
6. uncheck "**Show automatic thumbnail**"
7. **save changes**
8. **click on the name of your search engine** at the top of the "basics" page to use it.

**To use your search in a URL (to replace your existing search engine):**

```
http://www.google.com/cse?cx=000628392187335527771:2-d3w-aefr4&q=searchterms
```

You'll need to **replace the cx variable** with the value from your own custom search engine and **replace "searchterms" with %s** or whatever you usually use in your URL to indicate keyword placement.